# cosine function calculating scheme

Tags: scheme

Im making a scheme program that calculates
cos(x) = 1-(x^2/2!)+(x^4/4!)-(x^6/6!).......

whats the most efficient way to finish the program and how would you do the alternating addition and subtraction, thats what I used the modulo for but doesnt work for 0 and 1 (first 2 terms). x is the intial value of x and num is the number of terms

```
(define cosine-taylor
 (lambda (x num)
   (do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
      ((= i num))
      (if(= 0 (modulo i 2))
          (+ x (/ (pow-tr2 x (* i 2)) (factorial (* 2 i))))
          (- x (/ (pow-tr2 x (* i 2)) (factorial (* 2 i))))
      ))
   x))
```

Comment: Taylor is way too slow to converge. Have a look at Chebyshev polynomials. Or a Newton-Raphson scheme.

Comment: You could always pass the operator as an argument.  I'm looking at my copy of The Little Schemer (great book) because I think they have a function like this in the later chapters.

Comment: The code won't likely compile (because of the `let` usage) or would surely fail.  How hard have you tried?

Comment: yes right, that line was there by mistake from one of my trials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions:

1. whats the most efficient way to finish the program?  Assuming you want use the Taylor series expansion and simply sum up the terms `n` times, then your iterative approach is fine.  I've refined it below; but your algorithm is fine.  Others have pointed out possible loss of precision issues; see below for my approach.
2. how would you do the alternating addition and subtraction?  Use another 'argument/local-variable' of `odd?`, a boolean, and have it alternate by using `not`.  When `odd?` subtract when not `odd?` add.

> ```
> (define (cosine-taylor x n)
>   (let computing ((result 1) (i 1) (odd? #t))
>     (if (> i n)
>         result
>         (computing ((if odd? - +) result (/ (expt x (* 2 i)) (factorial (* 2 i))))
>                    (+ i 1)
>                    (not odd?)))))
>
> > (cos 1)
> 0.5403023058681398
> > (cosine-taylor 1.0  100)
> 0.5403023058681397
> ```

Not bad?

The above is the Scheme-ish way of performing a 'do' loop.  You should easily be able to see the correspondence to a `do` with three locals for `i`, `result` and `odd?`.

**Regarding loss of numeric precision** - if you *really* want to solve the precision problem, then convert `x` to an 'exact' number and do *all* computation using exact numbers.  By doing that, you get a natural, Scheme-ly algorithm with 'perfect' precision.

```
> (cosine-taylor (exact 1.0) 100)
3982370694189213112257449588574354368421083585745317294214591570720658797345712348245607951726273112140707569917666955767676493702079041143086577901788489963764057368985531760218072253884896510810027045608931163026924711871107650567429563045077012372870953594171353825520131544591426035218450395194640007965562952702049286379961461862576998942257714483441812954797016455243/7370634274437294425723020690955000582197532501749282834530304049012705139844891055329946579551258167328758991952519989067828437291987262664130155373390933935639839787577227263900906438728247155340669759254710591512748889975965372460537609742126858908788049134631584753833888148637105832358427110829870831048811117978541096960000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> (inexact (cosine-taylor (exact 1.0)  100))
0.5403023058681398
```

Comment: Instead of a separate Boolean and a `1/-1` select, why not have a `sign` variable that you multiply by -1 on each iteration...

Comment: Thanks. Updated with a different approach.  Choose `+` or `-` based on `odd?`.

Comment: +1 for showing exact/inexact. I guess in the range -pi/2...pi/2 the precision issue is moot anyway, though conceptually I think the computation of terms ought to be iterative (and `do` is fine by me). If you'd show how to limit the precision (to say, 1/10^20), it would be great (some way to approximate an exact value to the nearest exact multiple of 1/10^n).

Answer (score 2):

we should calculate the terms in *iterative* fashion to prevent the loss of precision from dividing very large numbers:

```
(define (cosine-taylor-term x)
  (let ((t 1.0) (k 0))
    (lambda (msg)
      (case msg
        ((peek) t)
        ((pull) 
          (let ((p t))
             (set! k (+ k 2))
             (set! t (* (- t) (/ x (- k 1)) (/ x k)))
             p))))))
```

Then it should be easy to build a function to produce an *n*-th term, or to sum the terms up until a term is smaller than a pre-set precision value:

```
(define t (cosine-taylor-term (atan 1)))
;Value: t

(reduce + 0 (map (lambda(x)(t 'pull)) '(1 2 3 4 5)))
;Value: .7071068056832942

(cos (atan 1))
;Value: .7071067811865476

(t 'peek)
;Value: -2.4611369504941985e-8
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers, I need to read up more to fully understand your code

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. reduce your input modulo 2pi - most polynomial expansions converge very slowly with large numbers
2. Keep track of your factorials rather than computing them from scratch each time (once you have 4!, you get 5! by multiplying by 5, etc)
3. Similarly, all your powers are powers of x^2. Compute x^2 just once, then multiply the "x power so far" by this number (x2), rather than taking x to the n'th power

Here is some python code that implements this - it converges with very few terms (and you can control the precision with the `while(abs(delta)>precision):` statement)

```
from math import *

def myCos(x):
  precision = 1e-5 # pick whatever you need
  xr = (x+pi/2) % (2*pi)
  if xr > pi:
    sign = -1
  else:
    sign = 1
  xr = (xr % pi) - pi/2
  x2 = xr * xr
  xp = 1
  f = 1
  c = 0
  ans = 1
  temp = 0
  delta = 1
  while(abs(delta) > precision):
    c += 1
    f *= c
    c += 1
    f *= c
    xp *= x2
    temp = xp / f
    c += 1
    f *= c
    c += 1
    f *= c
    xp *= x2
    delta = xp/f - temp
    ans += delta
  return sign * ans
```

Other than that I can't help you much as I am not familiar with scheme...

Comment: good answer; moreover, calculating the powers and the factorials will quickly get out of hand with very big resulting numbers *before* the division, and the ensuing loss of precision (translation: wrong results). Only this, iterative calculation is feasible, when we multiply the interim value by the result of division of `x^2` by `(k+1)*(k+2)`.

Comment: It is actually better to start with the smallest numbers if you want to minimize the loss of precision - this requires computing an array of values, then summing them "in reverse order". But that is really a tweak. When you bring data down to the -pi/2 - pi/2 domain you have 99% of the battle won.

Comment: of course the reduction of a value into a domain should be a task for a separate function, that's why I didn't include it in my answer. *Cosine* is lucky with its domain, but e.g. Fresnel integrals - not as much. :)

Comment: @willNess I disagree - if you want to compute a cosine you don't want to have to call two functions. Now your cosine function might call another function to reduce the domain but that has limited value in my opinion

Comment: I just meant that the range reduction is separate from the cosine-calculation as Taylor-series, in itself.

Answer (score 0):

For your general enjoyment, here is a stream implementation.  The stream returns an infinite sequence of taylor terms based on the provided `func`.  The `func` is called with the current index.

```
(define (stream-taylor func)
  (stream-map func (stream-from 0)))
(define (stream-cosine x)
  (stream-taylor (lambda (n) 
                   (if (zero? n)
                       1
                       (let ((odd? (= 1 (modulo n 2))))
                         ;; Use `exact` if desired...
                         ;; and see @WillNess above; save 'last'; use for next; avoid expt/factorial
                         ((if odd? - +) (/ (expt x (* 2 n)) (factorial (* 2 n)))))))))
> (stream-fold + 0 (stream-take 10 (stream-cosine 1.0)))
0.5403023058681397
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most streamlined function I could come up with.

It takes advantage of the fact that the every term is multiplied by (-x^2) and divided by (i+1)*(i+2) to come up with the text term.

It also takes advantage of the fact that we are computing factorials of 2, 4, 6. etc. So it increments the position counter by 2 and compares it with 2*N to stop iteration.

```
(define (cosine-taylor x num)

    (let ((mult (* x x -1))
          (twice-num (* 2 num)))

      (define (helper iter prev-term prev-out)
        (if (= iter twice-num)
          (+ prev-term prev-out)
          (helper (+ iter 2)
                  (/ (* prev-term mult) (+ iter 1) (+ iter 2))
                  (+ prev-term prev-out))))

      (helper 0 1 0)))
```

Tested at [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/Scheme).

Here are some answers:

```
   (cosine-taylor 1.0 2)
=> 0.5416666666666666
   (cosine-taylor 1.0 4)
=> 0.5403025793650793
   (cosine-taylor 1.0 6)
=> 0.5403023058795627
   (cosine-taylor 1.0 8)
=> 0.5403023058681398
   (cosine-taylor 1.0 10)
=> 0.5403023058681397
   (cosine-taylor 1.0 20)
=> 0.5403023058681397
```